# Why do I get network-related or instance-specific error on Membership.GetUser().Email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-identity

Here is the controller method where the application crashes

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SendInvitation(Guid appointmentId)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var ownerEmail = Membership.GetUser().Email; //error on this line
        _appointmentRepository.SendEmailToOwner(ownerEmail, appointmentId);
    }
    return Content("message sent to owner");
}
```

whenever I run my application everything works fine, database reading, writing, creating user(using Asp.net Identity) everything works smooth. But in a controller's method when try to get user's email it crashes.

When I set a breakpoint to this method, it goes through `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and crashes while it tries to access the email.

This is the **error** that is shown in **browser**:

```
  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection
  to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
  name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
 (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,error:26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

SQLExpress database file auto-creation error: 

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:

If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must have read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.
If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only requires read and write access to the application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database already exists within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is required because the web server account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.
```

Stack trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352431
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5363103
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +922
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5365937
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +5368242
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +76

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +131
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +89
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +27
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +386
```

Edit1:
I have created my own `ApplicationUser` class that inherits from  deafult `IdentityUser` class
which is

public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }

```
//public string Password { get; set; }

public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }
public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }

public string Company { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Comment { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public  string Phone{ get; set; }
public Boolean IsLockedOut { get; set; }
public DateTime DateTimeRegistered { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastLoginDateTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastActivityDateTime { get; set; }

public int PasswordFailureSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDateTime { get; set; }
public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

public int LicenseId { get; set; }
public License License { get; set; }
```

}

And now if I find the User with something like `_db.Users.Find(GuidID);` then i get the user instance with the email.

Is that the reason why I am getting error when i try to use default membership to get email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity introduced a completely new architecture that does not use the old concept of membership provider, which is what you are using when you call:

```
var ownerEmail = Membership.GetUser().Email;
```

Here is how you should access the user information in ASP.NET Identity.

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));         
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
if (user != null)
    _appointmentRepository.SendEmailToOwner(user.Email, appointmentId);
```